# jQuery - Triggering Events from Clicking on a Link Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, events

I'd like to trigger an event when a link is clicked both by clicking on it normally or by opening it in a new tab (e.g., middle click, ctrl + click, etc)

I've tried the following so far:

`$('a').click(myfunc)`  Doesn't capture middle clicks.

`$('a').mousedown(myfunc)` works, but it seems to be preventing the link from being followed even though my function doesn't call `event.preventDefault`.

Any ideas how to do this then?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try returning **true** from your handler function. Returning nothing can be interpreted by the browser as a void return and thus prevent the default action from being carried out.